# webRTC Coturn server return null iceCandidate?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I installed coturn server on an Ubuntu VPS for testing purposes, the testing of the coturn server on Trickle ICE looks great and everything is fine, but when I try to make a connection it returns null iceCandidate when peers are from different networks and it works fine when peers are in the same local network.

This is my Trickle ICE test results:

[image: Trickle ICE test results]

This is what I get when console logging the iceCandidate:

[image: iceCandidates]

And this is my iceservers:

```
const iceServers = {
iceServer: [
  {
   urls: "stun:stun.biodietfood.com:3478",
  },
  {
   urls: "turn:turn.biodietfood.com:3478?transport=tcp",
   username: "myuser",
   credential: "mypassword",
  },
 ],
};
```

And this is my code to make peer connection and sending an offer:

```
rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(); //create peer connection
rtcPeerConnection.setConfiguration(iceServers);
rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate; //generate ice candidate
rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidateerror = iceCandidateError;
rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = onAddStream; // generate the remote stream to send to other user
rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(localStream.getTracks()[0], localStream); // adding video
rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(localStream.getTracks()[1], localStream); // adding audio
rtcPeerConnection // creating offer
  .createOffer({ iceRestart: true })
  .then((sessionDescription) => {
    rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    socket.emit("offer", {
      type: "offer",
      sdp: sessionDescription,
      room: roomNumber,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The same code is used for creating an answer with little modifications.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: the screenshot of the trickle-ice page shows candidates arriving after the "done" line which is certainly unusual. However, it also shows mids 0 and 1 which should not happen with the unmodified page. Did you make any local modifications or do you have any extensions fudging with WebRTC installed? Does the same behavior occur in Chrome or Edge?

Comment: @Philipp Hancke
i appreciate your help actually i tried to connect using firefox the same problem happend, and about modification yes i did some modification to my coturn server but it seems that this was not the problem, the problem i noticed in the webrtc internals page is the ice servers is not included when i start the connections and finally the problem was in the iceServers object that i pass the key of the object should be iceServers not iceServer